# Add text to textview in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, for-loop, swift

How do i add text to a label or tableview, instead of updating the label/tableview?

```
var personArray: [Person] = [
Person(name: "Heine", sex: "Guy"),
Person(name: "Magnus", sex: "Girl"),
Person(name: "Sarah", sex: "Girl")
]

@IBOutlet weak var thePeople: UILabel!

func updatePeople()
{
    for peop in personArray{
        thePeople.text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use stringByAppendingString or stringWithFormat to append string

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Add text without updating? Do you want to append?

Comment: uh, the question is about a "textview", and the code is about `UILabel`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
thePeople.text = thePeople.text+"NewText"
```

or shorter

```
thePeople.text += "NewText"
```